# How can I decrease the header size on just Page 1?

Tags: header-footer

[image]

How can I adjust the header height of only Page 1 on my document? The title seems to be much too low on the page. It is fine for page 2 onwards.

Here is my template:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
% \documentclass[twocolumn,letterpaper,11pt]{article} for double columns

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
    bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,
    citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp,
    style=apa,
natbib]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float} % here for H placement parameter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



% Keywords command
\providecommand{\keywords}[2]
{
  \small    
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1
}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{type right header here}
\lhead{type left header here}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\addbibresource{references.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\title{This is the title of my document}
\author{Author XXXX }



\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
```

Comment: A better way to phrase this question would be "How can I reduce/remove the space above `\maketitle`?" Would you agree?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to phrase this question would be "How can I reduce/remove the space above `\maketitle`?"

You should look at what `\@maketitle` (in [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co)) does in order to see how to reduce the space above `\maketitle`:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

The first couple of lines are important. `\@maketitle` inserts a `\newpage` (to ensure the title is set at the top of a page), then `\null` (which is nothing, but uses up a regular line of text that has a height of `\baselineskip`) and finally `\vskip 2em` (an additional vertical gap) before setting the title. We can negate these insertions by way of the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}% Just for this example

\title{Document Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax% Avoid page break
\vspace*{\dimexpr-2em-\baselineskip}% Remove vertical space inserted by \@maketitle
\maketitle
\endgroup

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

We place the entire adjustment inside a scoped group (`\begingroup`...`\endgroup`) since it limits the redefinition of `\newpage` (to `\relax`, a no-op), restoring it after `\endgroup`.

Comment: I added that in but it didn't alter the space at the top of the page

Comment: I somehow manually adjusted it with: \usepackage[ margin=35mm, top=15mm, headheight=14.0pt]{geometry}

Comment: @kandyman Werner's answer worked for me, moving the title up. If you want it even further up then increase the `2em` in Werner's code (to perhaps `4em`).

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't change the title position at all for me. Using 4em didn't do anything either.

Comment: @kandyman: Then supply a minimal document that replicates the issue so we can find out what the issue is. Can you do that?

Comment: Should I edit the original question and add the code in there? Is that best?

Comment: @kandyman: Sure.